# preg_match_all match optional brackets

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, brackets

Trying to preg_match_all

```
#THING or [#THING]
```

This works for the first

```
/(#[A-Z]+)/
```

For the other with brackets, I thought something like this should work, but it doesn't.

```
/(\[?#[A-Z]+\]?)/
```

Ultimately, I want to match any of these

```
#THING [(#THING)] or [anything(#THING)anything]
```

Comment: Could you explain the requirements?

Comment: Your second regex matches `[#THING]`, as shown [here](https://regex101.com/r/KradXU/1)

Comment: `anything`s and the `()` should also be captured?

Comment: Need to make preg_replace_all to match and replace any of these - `#ANYUPPERCASE
[(#ANYUPPERCASE)]
[anything(#ANYUPPERCASE)anything]`
All characters should be captured in any of these.

Comment: Yes my original regex did work for [#THING] - my mistake

Comment: When it is not the pair of an unescaped `[`, the closing square bracket `]` [has no special meaning](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php). There is no need to escape it.

Comment: Same for } and ) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a robust/reliable pattern:

`~#[A-Z]+|\[[^#\]]*\(#[A-Z]+\)[^\]]*]~`

[Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kAyDHg/1)

```
~         #pattern delimiter
#[A-Z]+   #match hash symbol followed by one or more uppercase letters
|         #or
\[        #match an opening square bracket
[^#\]]*   #match zero or more non-hash/non-closing square bracket characters
\(        #match opening parenthesis
#[A-Z]+   #match hash symbol followed by one or more uppercase letters
\)        #match closing parenthesis
[^\]]*    #match zero or more non-closing square bracket characters
]         #match a closing square bracket
~         #pattern delimiter
```

This pattern is looking for a "hashtag" substring with no `[()]` characters in it OR a "hashtag" substring that will be tightly wrapped in `()` then loosely wrapped in `[]` which may also contain some characters before the `(` or after the `)`.

This pattern is efficient because it uses greedy quantifiers and it does not employ any capture groups.

Comment: @Delorimier Is your task about "validation" or "extraction"?  If your input string contains the brackets, do you actually want to extract the substring from `[` to `]` or do you only want the capital letters after th `#`?  I would like to better understand your task so that I can provide the best possible pattern for you.

Comment: Wow thanks - this looks a lot like what I finally came up with. I need to isolate to patterns from a string that can contain many. My needs got a little more complex since then, as the patterns can be embeded in another, ex:
ignore this part [before(#THIS) after[before(#ANOTHER]after]] ignore this part #CAPTURETHIS

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This seems to be working for me.

```
  ((\[(.*))?\(?#[A-Z]+\)?((.*)\])?)
```

Correctly matching these:

```
#ANYUPPERCASE
[(#ANYUPPERCASE)]
[anything(#ANYUPPERCASE)anything]
```

Comment: oops - not matching #ANYUPPERCASE

Comment: Code fixed in above example

Comment: This answer will actually match "imbalanced" square bracketed substrings: https://regex101.com/r/kAyDHg/2